# can i user same Route to render componenet by use of multiple links?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

this is my header and i want to redirect to one component but multiple link can not redirect on single route
my requirement is to redirect to /iframe route

````
```<Menu theme="dark" mode="horizontal">
          <SubMenu key="sub2" icon={<UserOutlined />} title="PHP Page">
          <Menu.Item key="13"><Link to="/iframe/1">PHP 3</Link></Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="14"><Link to="/iframe/2">PHP 4</Link></Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="15"><Link to="/iframe/3">PHP 5</Link></Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
          <Menu.Item key="6" icon={<BarChartOutlined />}>
            <Link to="/iframe/4">PHP 1</Link>
          </Menu.Item>
</Menu>```
````

This is my React Router
`<Context.Provider value={[context, setContext]}> <Switch> <Route exact path="/iframe" component={FirstPHP} /> <Route exact path="/r/4" component={FourthPage} /> </Switch> </Context.Provider>`

The question is when i click link on

````
```<Menu.Item key="13"><Link to="/iframe/1">PHP 3</Link></Menu.Item>
<Menu.Item key="14"><Link to="/iframe/2">PHP 4</Link></Menu.Item>
<Menu.Item key="15"><Link to="/iframe/3">PHP 5</Link></Menu.Item>```
````

it should redirect to

````
```<Route exact path="/iframe" component={FirstPHP} />```
````

in FirstPHP component without changes the link  tag

HELP me If is there any possible way

Comment: why can't you keep `to="/iframe"` instead of `to="/iframe/1"` , `to="/iframe/2"` and `to="/iframe/3"` ?

Comment: that  /1 /2 /3 will help me to render different iframe in that component that's why its important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `state` inside the `to` object instead of using `to` as a string as follows.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/iframe", state: { iframeNo: 1 } }}>PHP 3</Link>;
```

Then create a general component for `/iframe` route.

```
<Route exact path="/iframe" component={PHPComponent} />
```

Then extract `iframeNo` from the `PHPComponent` component and then inside that component you can conditionally render `FirstPHP`, `SecondPHP` and `ThirdPHP` components as follows.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const PHPComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { iframeNo } = location.state;

  console.log("history location details: ", location);
  console.log("extracted iframeNo: ", iframeNo);

  if (iframeNo === 1) {
    return <FirstPHP />;
  } else if (iframeNo === 2) {
    return <SecondPHP />;
  } else if (iframeNo === 3) {
    return <ThirdPHP />;
  }
};

export default PHPComponent;
```

Comment: Brillant way to pass and get the iframe id. thanks

Comment: Your logic is working properly. thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is some solution to solve the issue, try the simplest one:

You need to define a `Route` for each `iframe` in the routes provider:

```
<Context.Provider value={[context, setContext]}> 
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/iframe/1" component={FirstPHP} /> 
    <Route exact path="/iframe/2" component={SecondPHP} />
    <Route exact path="/iframe/3" component={ThirdPHP} />
    // and so on for other routes ...
  </Switch> 
</Context.Provider>
```